# Camera can't be found when class passed through as python object on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, plotly-dash, opencv, python

In the code below on my Raspberry Pi, when I pass the `VideoCamera()` class directly into the `gen()` function everything works as expected. However, when I pass the class through as an object (i.e. `cam = VideoCamera()`) the camera cannot be found (*'can't open camera by index'*). Notably, I don't have this issue on my Windows machine.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()

# passing the class through as an object variable does not seem to work on Raspberry Pi
cam = VideoCamera()

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

@server.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(cam), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    # This works (when 'cam' object deleted from code)
    # return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Webcam Test"),
    html.Img(src="/video_feed")
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the debug-mode to False solved it for me!

```
app.run_server(debug=True)
```